# Spring modular with more than one web module

Tags: spring, web, modular

I am trying to develop a modular web application which can be start and stop each module.

- Core
- web module (containing js, jsp especially for views of module content,   controller, service model etc.. for itself) v.1
- web module (containing js, jsp especially for views of module content,   controller, service model etc.. for itself) v.1
- jar module (contaning controller, service, model and other java) v.1
- jar module (contaning controller, service, model and other java) v.1
- jar module (contaning controller, service, model and other java) v.1

I need to maintain any module and upgrade itself while other modules working. I require for instance I can upgrade one module from version 1 to version 1.2 and other modules stays version 1.

You can thing this system as a quality management system. Each module has its own workflow, table structure etc...

How can I success this?

Answer (score 0):

look I suggest to use maven.

With maven every module will have a pom file, so let's say that you have module A and module b, and module b use module A, so the pom will be:

pom module A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    ....
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    ...
  </dependencies>

  ...

</project>
```

pom module B (use module A)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <properties>
    ....
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
      <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

      ...

  </dependencies>

  ...

</project>
```

And as you can see you have module A with version 2.0 and module B with version 1.0.

Here you can find more information: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: Yes I know that. Thanks for reply. But I already use maven and this structure. What if I neednto stop and change module A? Module B will be dsabled too. And 2. case Module B seems jar. I need both module web based (jsp pages, js etc) How o map/locate them related to applicationContext?